# What should be done about the tags for the Retrocycles/Armagetron Advanced game?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merging

Yesterday I asked a question about the game Retrocycles. As I noticed there was no tag for it, I made one. I later realized that "Retrocycles" is just the steam version's name and it is actually called Armagetron Advanced. As such, I updated the tags on my question, but now there are two tags for the same game.

There are no differences between the two versions as far as I can tell. As well, there is a version for the Fedora Linux operating system called Armacycles Advanced.

With all of this, I was wonder how questions about this game should be tagged?

Comment: We should probably pick one to be the 'main' tag and make the rest synonyms. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armagetron_Advanced) - the different names were chosen to avoid trademark issues. *"In 2007, "Armacycles Advanced" was chosen as an alternative secondary game name for the Fedora Linux operating system to avoid future potential trademark issues. For the same reason, "Retrocycles" was chosen as another secondary game name to use with the Steam distribution service in 2020."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone ahead and made the main tag [armagetron-advanced](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armagetron-advanced), as that is the current official project name. As I mentioned in the comments above, the other names were chosen for specific releases to avoid trademark issues [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armagetron_Advanced).

I've also added [retrocycles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retrocycles) and [armacycles-advanced](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armacycles-advanced) as synonyms, and added a [basic wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/armagetron-advanced/info) to the tag. Hopefully this will help future users find and use the tag correctly.